# Mocking entity - Enity Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, nunit, mocking

Is it possible to mock EF 3.5 entities. if so..how?

Comment: +1 - I'd like to know how this could be done with ninject.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Entity Framework is not well suited for mocking, due to lack of interfaces for example. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713343/c-unit-testing-generating-mock-datacontexts-linq-sql-classes) another SO question that deals with a simialr issue.

I think your best bet is to use the Moles framework from Microsoft (though it doesn't have the nicest API to work with from what I've seen. But hey, at least it's free)

Comment: I thought about extrating the interfaces from the partial classes and then mocking those, but I guess they would still have alot of dependecies inside..right?

Comment: What about creating an interface ICrud (CRUD). Then create a 1:1 Implementation with the View using whatever is necessary to work with the entity context. E.G. Create calls entitityContext.Entity.CreateEntry().  Would this create problems somehow?